# Change vim concealed text font size

Tags: vim, latex, folding

I want to increase the font size of my concealed latex symbols / titles. I haven't found a straightforward way to do this. Is there an obscure hack that would work?

It looks as though it has been done in Emacs AUCTeX: 
[aquamacs screenshot](http://aquamacs.org/latex/preview_working.png)

I'm aware that the formula in the screenshot comes from a png file, but at least it uses a bigger font for the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Vim does not allow you to change the font size (i.e, all fonts in Vim instance must be same size) it does allow you to apply special highlighting and/or a different font.  To do this you could, e.g., simply make all Conceal text bold and underlined:

```
:highight Conceal gui=bold,underline cterm=bold,underline
```

You could also change the default colors:

```
:highight Conceal gui=bold,underline cterm=bold,underline guifg=yellow guibg=red ctermfg=yellow ctermbg=red
```

You can also change the font used by Conceal text.  (Technically I think it is possible to specify a (bitmap) font of larger size, but that's not advised because it will screw up screen drawing):

```
:highight Conceal font=Monaco gui=bold,underline cterm=bold,underline guifg=yellow guibg=red ctermfg=yellow ctermbg=red
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is not possible in vim.  In console vim you are limited by your terminal's capabilities and in the gui there is only one setting for the font, `guifont`.

Comment: I see. This feature will only be useful for latex formulas. Thanks anyway